# What is the formal definition of indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know the definition of definite integral using limits (or sups and infs) in rectangles in a given partition. However I realized that I don't know the *formal* definition of indefinite integrals.

My question is really simple, what is the definition of indefinite integrals?

Comment: Probably something like this: $\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\mathrm d t=F(x)-F(a)$ where $a$ is any point of the domain of the function. But this mean that the constant value of an indefinite integral can be bounded... Mmm.

Comment: My understanding is that it's something like
$$
\int f(x)\,dx = \{ F(x): F'(x) = f(x) \quad \forall x \in \Bbb R\}
$$
but I don't have a reference to back that up.

Answer (score 5):

You can formally define the the concept of an anti-derivative and introduce the notation of an indefinite integral to mean the set of all anti-derivatives of a function. For the anti-derivative it would be something along the lines of:

> For a function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, we call a differentiable function $F : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ an **anti-derivative** of $f$ if $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.

Then introduce the following notation for the set of all anti-derivatives of $f$:
$$\int f(x) \, \mbox{d}x$$

Or, once you have the definite integral, you can use it to introduce the indefinite integral, for example:
$$\int f(x) \, \mbox{d}x = \int_a^x f(t) \, \mbox{d}t + C $$
This relies on the fact that the definite integral in the RHS is *one* anti-derivative of $f$ (this is the fundamental theorem of calculus) and you use the fact that all anti-derivatives can only differ up to a constant term, so adding the arbitrary constant gives you all of them.

Apostol does this in his *Calculus, Vol. 1* where he introduces the definite integral long before the "Leibniz notation for the indefinite integral".

Comment: If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on an Interval then it need not be the case that $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$. You seem to assume that if $f$ has an antiderivative on an interval then $f$ is Riemann integrable on that interval?

Answer (score 1):

I think the concept you'll find more about in the literature is "anti-derivative" rather than "indefinite integral." In all the settings I can think of, the definition of an anti-derivative $F$ first requires a derivative, say $D$, to be defined, and then is defined as "$F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$ iff $DF = f$". The reason that you'll find more about "anti-derivative" rather than "indefinite-integral" is that "anti-derivative" generalizes, while indefinite-integral comes from the classical case of the fundamental theorem of calculus that others have mentioned:

---

First, define the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$ of differentiable functions $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$. Then, an anti-derivative of $f$ is any $F : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ such that $\frac{d}{dt} F = f$. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that *some* $F$ exists for all Riemann-integrable $f$, and for *any* anti-derivative $F$, we have, for $\alpha \leq \beta$ in $[a,b]$,
$$
\int_\alpha^\beta f(x) \, dx = \left. F(x) \right|_\alpha^\beta = F(\beta) - F(\alpha).
$$
The idea of "indefinite integral" stems from the above by "leaving off $\alpha$ and $\beta$", which is what's meant in writing
$$
\int f(x) \, dx = F(x).
$$
But the more precise way of writing the above is via anti-derivatives: $\frac{d}{dt} F = f$.

---

Some generalizations of "anti-derivative" (but not necessarily "indefinite-integral") are found in functional analysis:

- A first concrete example: we say that $u \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ has a [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) ($u'$) in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ iff there exists $u' \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that the following integral equation holds:
  $$
  \left\langle u, - \frac{df}{dx} \right\rangle_{L^2} = \left\langle u', f \right\rangle_{L^2} \qquad\forall f \in C_c^1(\mathbb R).
  $$
  (You can make sense of this by integrating by parts.) In this case, we could instead say that $u' \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ has an anti-derivative ($u$) in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ if there exists $u \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that the same equation holds.
- More generally, "primitives" are solutions $u$ to the differential equation $\partial u = v$, where $u$ and $v$ are [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). ($v$ is known, and $u$ is to be found.) We could just as well have called $u$ an anti-derivative of $v$ rather than a primitive. In this case, there may not always be a good/reasonable way to write this as an integral equation like $v = \int u$.
- Measures $\nu$ with a [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) $f = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ could just as well be called anti-derivatives of their Radon-Nikodym derivatives. In this case, writing something like $\nu = \int f \, d\mu = \int \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \,d\mu$ makes sense, too.